# Sample size calculation for Mixed, Within-between ANOVA

Tags: anova, sample-size

I'm wondering if there is any formula for finding the sample size of mixed, within-between ANOVA. I have tried running it in G*power but I would like to know which formula G*power uses to calculate the sample size.

Answer (score 0):

page 182 of this [document](http://www.gpower.hhu.de/fileadmin/redaktion/Fakultaeten/Mathematisch-Naturwissenschaftliche_Fakultaet/Psychologie/AAP/gpower/GPower3-BRM-Paper.pdf). There is a ANOVA:
repeated
measures,
between–within
interactions formula in Table 3.

Comment: The link is not working, use this instead: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758/BF03193146.pdf